# If $gi_j = fi_j$ for all coproduct inclusions $i_j$ of $\amalg_{j\in J}A_j$ then $f=g$

Tags: category-theory

Suppose I have some small coproduct $\amalg_{j\in J} A_j$ with coproduct inclusions $i_j:A_j\to \amalg_{j\in J}A_j.$ Suppose I have two maps $f,g:\amalg_{j\in J}A_j\to X$ for which $fi_j=gi_j$ for all $j\in J$. Does this imply that $f=g$? If we're working on sets it does, but I'm not sure how to show this when working in general categories. It seems very simple, but I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: Yes. Recall that the universal property of coproducts (and universal properties in general) requires there be a _unique_ map out of the coproduct making the relevant diagram commute. Since $f$ and $g$ both make the diagram commute, they must be equal.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor That should be an answer. Actually, you could just copy and paste this text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Recall that the universal property of coproducts (and universal properties in general) requires there be a unique map out of the coproduct making the relevant diagram commute. Since $f$ and $g$ both make the diagram commute, they must be equal.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: But of course! How could I have missed it? Thank you so much!

Comment: It happens to all of us ^_^ Happy to help!